# Is it legal to record someone else's call in Arkansas if that recording is then never used?

Tags: phonecall, arkansas

I looked up Arkansas law and it says it's illegal to record someone else's call if you are not a part of that call and you didn't get at least one person's consent.

https://recordinglaw.com/united-states-recording-laws/one-party-consent-states/arkansas-recording-laws/

Then I talked to my friend who is a lawyer, and she says, "it's ok, you can record as much as you want as long as you don't attempt to use it anywhere. Recording other people's conversations that you are not a part of, and without permission is ok, as long as you don't use those conversations anywhere like evidence or something. Go on record as much as you want and keep it to yourself".

So technically you can record other people's conversations for yourself, and never use them. And this will be totally fine, as long as you keep those conversations to yourself.

Is this correct?

Comment: Do you mean **practically** record but not use them? **Technically** the link says **no** to even recording them. The caveat isn't "I am not going to use them" but "in a public place".

Comment: Yes, I mean: in Arkansas, one records a some one else's conversation without asking permission, and keeps that recording on his computer, doesn't share with anyone, doesn't use it. Just keeps it. Is this legal?

Comment: What your "not a lawyer" friend is saying is that you might "get away with it" if you don't reveal what you have done.

Comment: One thing your armchair-lawyer omitted to point out was that it's unlaw to ["possess"](https://www.lexico.com/definition/possess) such a recording regardless of it "leaking out" or not

Answer (score 4):

[Ark. Code 5-60-120](https://law.justia.com/codes/arkansas/2020/title-5/subtitle-6/chapter-60/subchapter-1/section-5-60-120/) is very clear that the act of *intercepting* is a crime. Not just "recording and using", not just "recording", but intercepting in any way. Specifically:

> It is unlawful for a person to intercept a wire, landline, oral,
> telephonic communication, or wireless communication, and to record or
> possess a recording of the communication unless the person is a party
> to the communication or one (1) of the parties to the communication
> has given prior consent to the interception and recording.

Intercepting is illegal, therefore it is not "okay". Perhaps the "sort of a lawyer" was speaking of the probability of getting caught doing it.

Comment: The lawyer said, even if this recording gets leaked, for example it get accidentally shared with someone else...it still will not have any consequences, because the person who recorded did not use the recording anywhere. The person who recorded will get in trouble ONLY IF he tried to use it somewhere for example court, internet. This person needs to PROACTIVELY try to use it, however, as long as he doesn't use it, there are no consequences

Comment: Perhaps the person was thinking in terms of civil suits rather than criminal law.

Comment: @user46500 The lawyer who said that was wrong. Lawyers aren't perfect and sometimes get things wrong, especially when they aren't being paid for their work and are only considering the issue informally.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking if it is legal to do something the law you quote says clearly is *not* legal.  Sometimes an answer here says “ask a real lawyer not random people in the internet.”

In this case I think you are getting a better answer from people on the internet.

No - the wording of that law says it is a criminal offense to record a phone call you are not part of.